# Validations during ActiveRecord callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to perform validations when creating new instances of an associated model within a before_save callback in ruby?

```
class Podcast < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :tracks, :dependent=>:destroy

before_save :generate_tracks

# creates the tracks played in the podcast 
def generate_tracks
    json = Hashie::Mash.new HTTParty.get("#{self.json_url}")
    json.sections.each do |section|
      if section.section_type=="track"
        track = self.tracks.build :name=>section.track.name
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The above code works fine but I was hoping to add something like this inside the if statement:

```
unless track.valid?
  errors[:base] << "OOPS, something went wrong whilst trying to build tracklist."
  return false
end
```

The problem with this code is that track.valid? always returns false because the Track model validates the presence of **podcast_id**. I don't feel so comfortable doing this in an after_create callback because I want to actually cancel podcast creation if the tracklist doesn't validate too. So what can I do?

Comment: Inside Track model can we do something like this.`def valid?
 true  end` _just by by passing the validation_

Comment: i would prefer not to bypass the validation. I'd sooner just remove the code that builds the tracklist. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me as though what you want is [validates_associated](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated), which would let you do:

```
class Podcast < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tracks

  validates_associated :tracks
end
```

That way, a podcast won't save unless it's associated tracks are valid.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't know about this! Should have read the manual a bit better I guess. Thanks, this pretty much works, although I did have to remove the validation on podcast_id inside track model to get it working. I think this is ok. Thanks a lot.